# php function "exec" not working for window's systeminfo command

Tags: php, cmd

I am trying to make a website give the user info about a certain computer when a user navigates to the page. I am using php 7.1. This is not outward facing and on a server that is not critical, so security is not my concern right now.

I have made sure that some of the timeout settings in php.ini are extended, but I may have missed something. I have tried this command directly in command line on the server and it has worked. I have tried other commands using the exec function and they have worked. I have turned display_errors on and no errors are appearing on the page, it is just a blank screen. The page finishes loading very quickly: less than a second.

This is all that is on the page I am trying to get to work

```
<?php 
$dCommand1 = 'systeminfo/s *ipaddress* /u *administrator* /p *password* > %TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt';
$dCommand2 = 'type "%TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt"';
$dCommand3 = 'del "%TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt"';
exec($dCommand1);

$dOutput = array();

exec($dCommand2, $dOutput);
foreach($dOutput as &$dRow){
    echo $dRow;
    echo '<br>';
}

exec($dCommand3);

?>
```

what has worked in php:

```
echo exec('ipconfig');
echo exec('whoami');
```

What worked in cmd:

```
systeminfo/s *ipaddress* /u *administrator* /p *password* > %TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt
type "%TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt"
del "%TEMP%\\sysinfo.txt"
```

I have turned display_errors on and no errors are appearing on the page, it is just a blank screen.
Thank you for any help you can give.

### Update

I added 2>&1 to the command and i got the following error while trying to run

```
systeminfo/s *ipaddress* /u *administrator* /p *password* 2>&1
```

*ERROR: The user name or password is incorrect.*

However, the password and username are correct, because the same command is working in the command line.

Comment: This looks really suspect

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` to read the file, instead of using a PHP function like `file()` or `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: have you set PHP error_reporting level to `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: I have error reporting set to all

Comment: i could use 'file', but the problem is that the file is not being written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to use domain credentials. Somehow in the command line for the server, I could get away with using local credentials that were on the computer I was trying to get information from, but on the php page, I had to use domain credentials to get access to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to redirect the output to a file. Get rid of the redirection and just read the results directly.

```
$dCommand1 = 'systeminfo/s *ipaddress* /u *administrator* /p *password*';
exec($dCommand1, $dOutput);
foreach ($dOutput as $dRow) { // no need for &
    echo "$dRow<br>";
}
```

Comment: that does cut down on some lines of code but does not solve my problem

Comment: If you do it with output redirection, can you type the `sysinfo.txt` file in a CMD window?

Comment: I don't know Windows, maybe there's some permissions issues with the `systeminfo` command, so the webserver user can't run it.

Comment: i can type any of the commands i am having trouble with into the command line directly and it works

Comment: I know that. What I'm asking about is using PHP to execute systeminfo, then using CMD to read the file. I'm trying to find out if the problem is with running systeminfo or reading the file.

Comment: the problem is running systeminfo. the file is never created